# What is the external pivoting in the quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I find on the internet about the external pivoting in quick sort but did not get anything about it. Please explain me is this any concept in quick sort?

Comment: Please share what material did you read and what could you make out of it so that others can help from there.

Comment: I think external pivoting applies to the external quicksort algorithm described at http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/externalQuicksort.html.  It is similar but different from the (usual) quicksort algorithm as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort which has an interesting review of the algorithm including a discussion on choice of pivot.